# Can't choose value from rich select with enableManualInput if value is substring of another value

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have rich:select component with enableManualInput set "true".

```
<rich:select value="#{productBean.item.cargoType}"
             enableManualInput="true"
             converter="#{cargoTypeSelectConverter}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.cargoTypes}"
                   var="cargo"
                   itemLabel="#{cargo.name}"/>
</rich:select>
```

cargoTypes list contains next values: "gazoline", "gazoline class A", "gazoline class B". If I try to select row "gazoline" will be selected row "gazoline class A". Any other rows selected without problem. So, it appear only if I try to select row which is substring of another. If we change "gazoline" to "gazoline class C", everything will be fine.
Any suggestions how I can fix it? 
I use: richfaces 4.2.3.Final

**UPD:** here is thread at richfaces forum where I ask this question too:
https://community.jboss.org/thread/236266

**In short:** I think that problem appear because of __save method in select.js (richfaces component repos). Particularly in __getClientItemFromCache call. To fix it we need to clear cache or to use __getClientItem method instead of __getClientItemFromCache.

**UPD2:** totally found this issue in bug tracker:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12613

Comment: Have you tryied the `selectFirst` property to false? Also if that doesn't work, use the `clientFilterFunction` and implement a custom client filter to this select component.

Comment: selectFirst is not working. Custom filter function can work, thanks for idea. But also it's just workaround and I don't imagine how this function must work. If it will search just for particularly match I fix issue but search in rich:select will be bad. If it will search any other way we again will take just fist element.

Comment: I personally don't consider it as a bug since the enableManualInput was designed to be a `like 'string%' ` function as in database and therefore has this `clientFilterFunction` that is your own way of reimplementing this filter. I can't see it as an workaround.

Comment: And I'm not say that it filters wrong. I just say that I can't choose row from filtered list. If I see row and can't choose it - it's a bug. clientFilterFunction use in 2 different ways. One for filter list, second for apply choosed value. I need 2 different function for this different tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JIRA issue you linked](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12613) states, that the problem has been fixed in context of another [JIRA issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12312), which has been marked as fixed for RichFaces 4.5.0.CR1. So the solution to your problem would be to **use RichFaces 4.5.0.CR1 or newer**.